# python programming-reading from multiple files

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi I'm having trouble with a university assignment asking us to create a python program which

1. asks the user to input three filenames containing words, in the format `file1` `file2` `file3` where each filename is separated by a space. This input is assigned to variable `FList`.
2. The program splits `FList` into three filenames `file1`, `file2` and `file3`.
3. For each file in `FList`, the program reads in the words from the file and stores these strings into their respective lists: `wordList1`, `wordList2` and `wordList3`. For example, words from `file1` would be assigned to `wordList1`.
4. The program asks the user to input a search word and assigns it to `searchWord`.
5. The program searches `wordList1`, `wordList2`, and `wordList3` for `searchWord`, and counts the number of matches in each file and assigns the result to their respective variables: `file1Results`, `file2Results` and `file3Results`.

---

```
Flist=raw_input("Please enter the three filenames seperated by spaces")  
Flist=Flist.split()  
file1=open(Flist[0],"r")     
wordList1=file1.read().split()  
file1.close()  
file2=open(Flist[1],"r")    
wordList2=file2.read().split()   
file2.close()   
file3=open(Flist[2],"r")  
wordList3=file3.read().split()  
file3.close()  

searchWord=raw_input("Which word would you like to search ")
file1Results=wordList1.count(searchWord)  
file2Results=wordList2.count(searchWord)  
file3Results=wordList3.count(searchWord)  
print "file1Results=",file1Results  
print "file2Results=",file2Results  
print "file3Results=",file3Results
```

I've made three .txt files on my desktop named `output.txt`, `output2.txt`, `output3.txt` but for some reason when i test run the program, it says that `output2.txt` does not exist.

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would cause the error you mention. Are you sure you're not making a typo in the filename (either in the actual file system, or when you submit the filename to the Python program)? Can you show the traceback of the exception?

Comment: Should it be Flist=Flist.split(" ")?

Comment: What directory is your program in, relative to your .txt files, and how are you referring to the .txt files on your command line?

Comment: ... what happens if you enter `output.txt output.txt output.txt` instead? Does it complain about that file?

Comment: @White `.split()` will split on whitespace by default.

Comment: As @Bickknight said, the answer will be in the traceback (The text around 'File does not exist') We have to guess unless you give more info.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what your input is, but it sounds like you are looking for the file in the wrong directory.

```
f1 = open('output1.txt')
```

would search for the output in the folder the python script is being run.
What you probably need is something like this:

```
desktop_path = 'C:/Users/YOURNAME/Desktop/'
f1 = open(desktop_path + 'output1.txt') # open(desktop_path + Flist[0])
```

Also, what maybe a problem is

```
Flist.split()
```

which works as follows:

> For example, ' 1  2   3  '.split() returns ['1', '2', '3'], and '  1  2   3  '.split(None, 1) returns ['1', '2   3  '].

You can find more on this [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Comment: ... and yet he doesn't get any error for output.txt, which is presumably in the same directory?

Comment: Correct. I was adding the second part that may be the issue with the problem, but as I don't know either the input or output. I am just listing best guesses.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())
```

to the start of your script and run it; it will tell you what directory you are currently working in.

If I save a script on my desktop and run it by double-clicking, it runs with `c:\windows\system32` as the current directory. I suspect yours is doing the same and you happen to have a file called `output.txt` in that directory.

If that is the case, you can use `os.path.join(r"path\to\desktop\", filename)` to make it look in the right location.